# Why Toolbar not showing on iOS display using Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, toolbar

I want to display very simple Toolbar using xamarin on iOS, but I can't see the toolbar on display.

I use this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   x:Class="Test.MainPage">

        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
          <ToolbarItem Text="Example Item"
                       IconImageSource="https://img.icons8.com/cute-clipart/64/000000/menu.png"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Priority="0" />
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

</ContentPage>
```

There are no errors in the code and the display is empty..

What needs to change to see the toolbar ?

Comment: How you navigate to this mainpage? Can you post the navigation code?

Comment: If you are navigation from App.xaml.cs like this Application.Current.MainPage =new MainPage();,  then change it to Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

Comment: I don't have a navigation code can I get clear documentation for this ?

Comment: How you navigate to your MainPage from App.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 1):

Are you putting your page in NavigationPage? By default ContentPage does not have Navigation bar (Toolbar), you must put your page in NavigationPage, after that Navigation bar will show up with its functionality.
have a look at here : [Xamarin.Forms Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/)

So I assume you should do something like this

```
public App ()
{
   MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MainPage());
}
```